# Windows Explorer use Full File Path

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, window

If I navigate to **My Computers**, **Documents**, or **Home Folder** with Windows Explorer via the location text field, the absolute path isn't displayed.

This obfuscation is an anti-feature. How do I enable the absolute path to show itself?

Comment: There is a simple option to enable Absolute path on title bar but haven't stumbled upon anything about what you are asking